# Why does 'apt/yum install' JUST NOT show actual package URLs?

Tags: linux, yum, packages, apt

I know there are commands to show package(*.rpm/*.deb) URLs without download:

```
#apt
apt download --print-uris PACKAGE
#yum
repoquery --location PACKAGE
yumdownloader --urls PACKAGE
```

But for god's sake, why does `apt/yum install` not show the actual package URLs being downloaded?

```
#apt just show an abstract url, not the actual. (actual is .../pool/...deb)
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 socat amd64 1.7.3.1-1 [321 kB]
#yum neither show url
---> Package socat.x86_64 0:1.7.3.2-2.el7 will be installed
```

As I know so far, there is no option/preference to config to show package urls.

I am really sick of this. Can anyone tell me is why they always trying to hide the actual package URLs?

Comment: I do not know where should i post. Ok, I will delete it from stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer for `apt`.

The reason why the actual URLs aren't printed is because of abstraction, the same way why classes have getVar() and setVar() functions instead of a public variables. The packages are meant to be retrieved by a package manager, not by hand, so there is no need to show URLs by default.

The current format displays information on the release and component of a package that a URL does not reveal.

Consider if the naming scheme for the packages changed. Then, a URL would be missing information on the version and architecture of a package.

Consider if the URL itself changed. The current output format for downloading packages can stay the same, but this would not the case if an URL was shown by default.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But users have the RIGHT to know what is going on under the hood, they can not just hide this.

Comment: But to get these commands, it cost user too much time to try which command is actually useful!  It was not simple. These commands are precious!

Comment: Nobody think apt/yum is kind of agains law of the right to know where it is going on?